# file read merge and create URL using nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, html5-audio

i am building a nodejs application built using nodejs and express.
the application basically works as a REST URL Calls. front end is written in angularjs.

currently i have to built an application which can play sound and display its text. for simplicity purpose we have extracted the text from the wav file and placed it inside another folder.

In one folder we have a collection of wav files running into thousands and in another folder on same level we have a text files containing all the text

```
WAV (FOLDER)
TEXT (FOLDER)
```

Under WAV folder i have a file

```
2044197581O0140602 - zIgnacio, Ohmar.wav
```

Under Text Folder i have the same file containing its speect text

```
2044197581O0140602-zIgnacio,Ohmar.txt
```

This is exact filename. The problem is that i have to built a system so that all these files can be displayed on the front end . and while playing its text should be shown.(timing is not important here).

I an using nodejs. i know that i cannot upload thousands file from front end. so it has to be done from back end.

can there be a where i can merge both these files into meaningful JSON JS objects and also return the Object URL using nodejs.

Please suggest any good way to handle this architecture using nodejs

I have written this

```
function FolderReaderMerger(path,pathToMerge,cb)
{

  log("Reading File/Folder");
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, files1) 
  {
      fs.readdir(pathToMerge, function(err, files2) 
      {
        log(files1);
        log(files2); 
         var obj ={};
         obj.wav = (files1);
         obj.wavText = (files2);
         cb(obj);

      });
  });

}
```

but i need to convert wav file conplete path as a URL and add it to JSON. sp that i can hit that url and play that file browser side. any help

TO call above function

```
FolderReaderMerger(WAV,TEXT,function(res)
    {
        log("COMBINED FILES");
        log(res);
        log(res.length);
        global.combined = res;
      });
```

And a get URL

```
app.get("/api/getCombinedFiles",function(req,res)
{

    res.send(global.combined); 

 });
```

I am able to get the list of files from both folder. But i need to play the audio files on the client side

Comment: Does the WAV filename really contain extra spaces? Why can you not just do two AJAX requests, one for the text file and one for the corresponding wav file?

Comment: these are actual files. i dont need complete files using AJAX as the fiels runs in Gigabytes. so i am planning to combine them into  as a JSON with wavfile with text file and a URL to the boith file. so that the front end can stream data or something like that

Comment: put the files in your static folder and create a url using your static path

Answer (score 0):

I had been able to come up with this. i send the file using teh URL sendFile="some file" and then the node checks for that file. if successful i start getting the stream on my client side and i put it directly into video src. But i need morecontrol over this. such as when user click on certain timeline so that i can directly start strweaming from there.

app.get is used to get the location of the folder where i store the files.
used just express and nodejs

```
function FolderReaderMerger(path,pathToMerge,cb)
{

  log("Reading File/Folder To Combine : ");
  fs.readdir(path, function(err, audio) 
  {
      fs.readdir(pathToMerge, function(err, audioText) 
      {

         var obj ={};
         global.list.audio =audio;
         global.list.audioText =audioText;

         obj.audio = audio;
         obj.audioText = audioText;

         cb(obj);

      });
  });

}


app.get("/audio",function(req,resp)
{
    log("App Audio File Serv : ");
    var playFile = req.param("playFile");
    var filePath =  {};
    filePath.status =false;


    if(playFile!=undefined)
    { 
    log("Params File : "+playFile);
   /* log("Requested URL : "+req.url);
    log("Total Audio Files : "+global.list.audio.length);*/
    var i =0;
    while(i!=global.list.audio.length)
    {
      if(playFile==global.list.audio[i])
      {
        log("File Found : "+playFile);
        //get files location
        log(app.get("audioPath")+playFile);
        filePath.status = true;

        var filePath = app.get("audioPath")+playFile;
        log("FILE PATH : "+filePath);

        var stat = fs.statSync(filePath);
        log(stat);
        log(stat.size);
        resp.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
            'Content-Length': stat.size
        });

        var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
        // We replaced all the event handlers with a simple call to readStream.pipe()
        log("Streaming.......");
        readStream.pipe(resp);
      }
      else
      {
        log("Requested Resource Not Found");


      }
      i+=1;
    }
    //readStream  = fs.createReadStream(app.get("audioPath"));
    }
    else
    {
      log("Requested Params Not Found");
      resp.send(filePath);
    }
 });



http.listen(app.get("PORT"),function()
{
consolelog("--------------------------------------------------------");
console.log("Server Started On PORT: "+app.get("PORT"));
console.log("All NPM Initialized");
console.log("Please Wait Checking Connection Status...");
console.log("--------------------------------------------------------");

    });
```

ANy help would be appreciated.